# How to display different array on different pages of page scroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am beginner in iOS development. I am creating a page scroller of two pages and displaying data from two different arrays in table view. but I am unable to display that data on pages. I am getting same array on both the pages. here is code where I am setting data in table view with respect to the index of pages in page scroller. BTIobj is object of class from where my index of pages is coming,

Pagescroller.m

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [appDelegate.tableDetailDataAD count];
}


//CELL FOR ROW AT INDEX PATH
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

   if(BTIobj.indx==0)
   {
        NSString *title=[[appDelegate.tableDetailDataAD objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date1"];
        cell.textLabel.text = title;
        NSString *str=[[appDelegate.tableDetailDataAD objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name1"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=str;
       NSLog(@"AD data:%@",[appDelegate.tableDetailDataAD description]);

   }

   if(BTIobj.indx == 1)
    {
        [tableView reloadData];
        NSString *title=[[appDelegate.tableDetailDataIH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date1"];
        cell.textLabel.text = title;
        NSString *str=[[appDelegate.tableDetailDataIH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name1"];
        NSLog(@"AD2 data:%@",[appDelegate.tableDetailDataIH description]);
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=str;
        [self.indianHolidaysTableView reloadData];
    }

    //Formatting texts
    cell.textLabel.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(153/255.0) blue:(204/255.0) alpha:1] ;
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];


    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading different data source (array) you need to handle the number of rows also based on the BTIindex selection 
Here

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [appDelegate.tableDetailDataAD count];
}
```

And one more thing, reloading table view inside the cellforrowatindexpath leads to recursive call.

Here

```
   if(BTIobj.indx == 1)
    {
        [tableView reloadData];
        NSString *title=[[appDelegate.tableDetailDataIH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date1"];
        cell.textLabel.text = title;
        NSString *str=[[appDelegate.tableDetailDataIH objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name1"];
        NSLog(@"AD2 data:%@",[appDelegate.tableDetailDataIH description]);
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=str;
        [self.indianHolidaysTableView reloadData];
    }
```